# Google Pay in Cordova webview causing "Unexpected developer error, please try again later." error

Tags: android, cordova, google-pay

Has anyone gotten Google Pay to work using the Cordova webview?

I create an Android Cordova project, and add "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser". I then alter index.html to contain:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

- I run and am presented with the demo page.
- I click on the "Buy with GPay" button underneath "Basic example".
- I login to my Google account.
- I'm then told "Unexpected developer error, please try again later."

If I do the same thing in Chrome, it works fine.

I'm running a recent Android System WebView (88.0.4324.181) so I don't think that's the problem.

Does anyone know what could be wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Google Pay doesn't work inside of a webview. Google Pay needs to be able to launch a popup which isn't supported by webviews.

Comment: That's unfortunate but it makes sense. I wish the error message was a little more specific than "Unexpected developer error" though. Thanks for the information, @Soc!